# Rails - How to store uploads on my database server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, architecture, paperclip, carrierwave

In my Rails app, for HIPAA reasons, I need to keep all my data stored on a separate server from my web application. This is simple to do with the database, but what's the best way to allow my rails app (on the web server) to access uploads on the filesystem of the database server? Or should I just store the uploads in the database (mysql)?

I'm using Rails 3.2 and Paperclip, but could switch to Carrierwave or another solution

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I just store the uploads in the database (mysql)

**No.** I will point you here for a better explanation [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay#)

> what's the best way to allow my rails app (on the web server) to access uploads on the filesystem of the database server

I would probably create another web server with a separate rails app that was responsible solely for serving up files from it's local filesystem through some authenticated API.

It looks like people *do* use Amazon S3 successfully with HIPAA-compliant websites for file storage.

- [Can you create a HIPAA compliant Amazon S3 Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657586/can-you-create-a-hipaa-compliant-amazon-s3-web-application)
- [Amazon White Paper - Creating HIPAA-compliant Medical Data Applications with AWS](http://awsmedia.s3.amazonaws.com/AWS_HIPAA_Whitepaper_Final.pdf)
- Googling "amazon hipaa compliance" turns up quite a bit of info. **I would look into this before building my own infrastructure for storing files**.

Comment: I wanted to go the S3 route initially, but the volume of uploads is fairly low plus it's tough to sell this sort of thing to our non-technical customers who are super concerned about security. I would think it would be relatively simple to access files on the filesystem of a server on the same local network.

Answer (score 0):

you can configure paper clip to store your documents on amazon s3

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#storage

http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3